# Android Emulator problems, to do with the .apk

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, adb

My emulator stopped working whilst making an app and kept saying it couldn't install the .apk in the console whilst running. When running the emulator in the manager it loads fine but obviously doesn't have an app to load.

When I try and run the app in the emulator it gives me the error and then loads up the phone without my app on it. This suggests its the apps fault in my mind, so i created a new project which i left untouched where it just said "hello world", even when trying to run this I get the same issue.

I've tried other peoples responses on here such as moving the apk file but that was to no avail, I've ended up redownloading and installing the sdk files but the same error persists. I'm new to this & appreciate any help.

My console after attempting to run app:

```
[2014-03-28 19:57:52 - LiverpoolPolls] ------------------------------
[2014-03-28 19:57:52 - LiverpoolPolls] Android Launch!
[2014-03-28 19:57:52 - LiverpoolPolls] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-28 19:57:52 - LiverpoolPolls] Performing com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadhomemenu activity launch
[2014-03-28 19:57:52 - LiverpoolPolls] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'emulator'
[2014-03-28 19:57:52 - LiverpoolPolls] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'emulator'
[2014-03-28 19:57:54 - LiverpoolPolls] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-03-28 19:57:54 - LiverpoolPolls] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-03-28 20:02:12 - LiverpoolPolls] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-28 20:02:12 - LiverpoolPolls] Uploading LiverpoolPolls.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-28 20:02:18 - LiverpoolPolls] Installing LiverpoolPolls.apk...
[2014-03-28 20:04:34 - LiverpoolPolls] Failed to install LiverpoolPolls.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-03-28 20:04:34 - LiverpoolPolls] (null)
[2014-03-28 20:04:35 - LiverpoolPolls] Launch canceled!
```

I shall download that other emulator and see where that gets me.

Comment: post the complete error

Comment: Post the logcat; also eclipse emulators suck! Try using http://www.genymotion.com/ :)

Comment: I've added the console above which shows the error, further help appreciated!